# S19A100N expanding past the end of my screen

Tags: windows-xp, display, resolution

I just bought a Samsung SA100 19" monitor (S19A100N).  I set my resolution for `1366 x 768` as recommended, but my desktop is too big.  Horizontally I see about 2/3 of the desktop.  If I move my mouse all the way to the right, it will "scroll" to show me the remaining portion.

I tried running the MagicTune software from Samsung, but it crashes my computer every time I open it.

- Windows XP SP3
- SiS 661 integrated video w/ the UniVGA 3 driver (v. 6.14.10.3930)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `SiS 661` just does not support that resolution.  I installed an AGP expansion card and now the monitor works perfectly fine.